# How to make back button tappable in navigation bar with unwind segue using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've created a custom view with button to my nav bar. See photo: [custom view with button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J47iA.png)

I have inputed this code in my view controller also and its load this view with button to my nav bar, so I can change the position and side of the button.

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.backButtonView)

        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

It's now what I want, but how can I make this button tappable, so I can make some action or make a custom unwind segue. [How it looks in simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQSSS.png)

Comment: You have to add target on the custom button with call back on main controller

Comment: @Vishal_VE can you share how it should look like please?

Comment: can you share how you create the backButtonView

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom button like below

```
lazy var backButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "icBack"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(leftBarButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

Use this button as the custom view for your UIBarButtonItem

```
let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.backButton)
self.navigationController?.delegate = self
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

and create the selected method as below.

```
@objc func leftBarButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: “unwindToXVC”, sender: self)
}
```

Comment: My image become big and how I can change the size of this? Also action didn't work, maybe you know how to make this solution, like was told today : You have to add target on the custom button with call back on main controller

Comment: Normally we will have to provide the icons at 1x,2x, and 3x sizes for iOS assets. for navigation bar icons, the required icon sizes are 24x24 pt (72x72 px @3x). try providing the icon at the required sizes. In the above example, I have already added the button target. **button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(leftBarButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)**

Comment: Looks good, thank you, but how can I use it with custom unwind segue?

Comment: @mozeX please see I have edited my answer with a sample segue.